# Not able to access Springboot deployed at GCP compute instance at port 8080

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I have a springboot app running at port 8080 at one of the GCP instance. I have turned on the firewall rules to allow traffic to port 8080. But still when I try to access the deployed port [ http://external-IP:8080/myservice ] I am not able to. From browser I get "This site can be reached" and from postman I get the error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED :8080

I am not sure if there are any specific firewall rules or anything that I need to set.

[image]

Comment: Is the app bind to  0.0.0.0? I suspect it is running in 127.0.0.1 or localhost

Comment: In addition to @Ferregina Pelona 's, suggestion, you may check this documentation on [Setting up the firewall for your Springboot Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/kotlin-springboot-compute-engine). Under "Create and configure a Compute Engine instance" Number 3. I'd also suggest to avoid using 0.0.0.0 and using "all" for the ports when creating the firewall rule to avoid vulnerability and security breach.

Comment: @OnlyJams   I already did what you have mentioned and my protocol and ports is set to  Allow All.

Comment: @JamesStan can you confirm the app is listening on 0.0.0.0?

Comment: @JamesStan 
Make sure that the Target tag "http-server" on the Firewall rule matches the Network tags on your deployed VM Instance. Also check the firewall of your VM Instance if the port 8080 is allowed.


run this command on the Cloud Shell, to verify the network tags of your VM
gcloud compute instances describe instance-name --zone=<zone> 


and run a netstat -a command inside the VM Instance include the result as a screenshot on your topic